# Object.create, not correct when JSON.stringify the object

Tags: javascript

I have tried to creates a new object `b` from object `a` using `Object.create`

```
var a ={}; 
var b = Object.create( a );

a.n = 1;
b.m = 2;
```

When I iterate two object through `for .. in ..` its showing correct values . but JSON.stringify not printing correct string .

```
JSON.stringify( b )
```

It supposed to print like `{"n":1,"m":2}` . but it print like `{"m":2}` only . Any suggestions why?

I have added it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Nxs/)  . link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V3Nxs/

Comment: What does stringify print?

Comment: @Thilo please check jsfiddle link

Comment: jsfiddle is blocked here. And including the complete question makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: @rab: No, put the relevant information **in the question**. Or don't you want to make it easy for people to help you?

Comment: Where is the problem? That b.n=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V3Nxs/2/

```
for( var k in b ){
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
    html.push( 'b.'+ k +':' + b[k] );
}
```

1. You need to use hasOwnProperty
2. I changed the index of the second for loop

If you look at what Object.create does, the first argument you pass in is the prototype of the new object.  That means that b has everything a has, in the prototype chain.  hasOwnProperty fixes this because it only returns true if the property tested is on the object itself, not somewhere up in the prototype chain.

now it behaves as i think you expect.

Answer (score 4):

This is becasue `n` is the prototype property of `b` and `JSON.stringify` only works for those properties which returns true for `hasOwnProperty` on the object.

Comment: Specifically: `JSON.stringify` only includes *enumerable*, *own* properties, not properties inherited from the prototype, and not non-enumerable properties.

Comment: @Ankur Your answer helps with my issue. what is solution for print correct `JSON.stringify` ?

Answer (score 0):

`b.n` not being defined is expected behavior. To get what you want you might want to try this.

```
var a = {};
var b = {a:a};

a.n = 1;
b.m = 2;
```

now `b.a.n` is set to `1` and `JSON.stringify` includes it in the output.